# BIOS freezes when USB hard drive is plugged in

Tags: hard-drive, bios

I have a [Fit-PC3](http://fit-pc.com/wiki/index.php/Fit-PC3) with a Phoenix BIOS (Securecore Tiano v2.1), and when I turn it on with a Samsung 3TB USB external hard drive (similar to [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00C9TEOCA/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1)) plugged in, it freezes on the BIOS screen (I am unable to press F2 to enter the BIOS setup).

When I unplug the drive, it boots fine.  I can then plug in the drive later, and it works perfectly.

The drive has its own power supply plugged in to the mains.

I have changed the boot order in the BIOS, so my internal HD is listed first, and the external HD is listed second, and marked as disabled (there is an "!" next to it).

I have turned off UEFI boot and turned on Legacy mode.

I have overwritten the master boot record on the drive with zeroes using `dd`.

I have tried plugging it into different USB ports.

Possible duplicates: [Ext HDD = Frozen @ Splash Screen](https://superuser.com/questions/1130087/ext-hdd-frozen-splash-screen), [Shuttle FB51 mobo does not boot with external USB drive attached](https://superuser.com/questions/445354/shuttle-fb51-mobo-does-not-boot-with-external-usb-drive-attached), [Troubleshooting a failed hard-drive that halts BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/645725/troubleshooting-a-failed-hard-drive-that-halts-bios)

The results are the same if I plug in the hard drive via a USB hub but when plugged in to another PC (ASUS BIOS) that PC boots fine.

Any ideas how to get it to boot?

Comment: What is your operating system and is this happening with both USB2 and USB3? I once encountered a PC that couldn't boot with anything connected on USB3, and the problem went away when upgraded to Windows 10.

Comment: Is the HDD being powered through the USB port? Maybe it's drawing too much power.

Comment: I have seen this a few times..many years ago.  I don't recall what I did as a workaround besides unplugging it and plugging it in when it was on.  I think one thing I might've tried was plugging in a USB hub and then plugging the device into the USB hub, that might have worked i'm not sure. You could try that

Comment: The OS is Lubuntu 18.04

Comment: The HDD is powered via a separate power adapter plugged in to the mains.

Comment: I will try plugging it in via a USB hub this evening.

Comment: Is this happening with both USB2 and USB3?

Comment: @harrymc This is happening with USB2.  The USB3 ports on the fitpc stopped worked a few months ago.

Comment: @barlop see my update: plugging in via a USB hub did not change the results :-(

Comment: The state of the Fit-PC3 does not sound all that encouraging. Did you try the disk on another computer?

Comment: @AndyBalaam usb hubs stopped working could be motherboard or could be power supply affecting the motherboard, can you change the power supply?

Comment: @barlop using the usb hub didn't help, making me think it's probably not a power issue.  The HDD has its own power supply.  I do not have another one to try.

Comment: @harrymc my other PC (ASUS BIOS) boots fine with the drive plugged in.  The drive works fine on the fitpc after boot - it just causes the BIOS to crash.

Comment: Do you have a spare 2TB or smaller drive to test in the enclusure with? Asking since older firmware did not always anticipate drives >2TiB and given a 2011 CPU the firmware might be a bit old).

Comment: Is it the latest BIOS? [This list](http://fit-pc.com/wiki/index.php/Fit-PC3_BIOS_ROM_Files) doesn't explicitly mention USB, but maybe `BIOS Setup customization` adds or changes something relevant.

Comment: Well, I had same problem, first option is - unplug external drive during boot (but it's not a solution). This happens because your PC trying to. boot from plugged external drive, so second option is - change boot priority.

Comment: @Hennes my previous drive (1TB, powered via USB) did work.

Comment: @ArchilLabadze thanks - I have already tried changing the boot priority and it didn't help.

Comment: Not an expert on this but if you can otherwise boot to BIOS (w/o that HDD), try changing one parameter at a time. It could be that some setting in BIOS is causing this. On my desktop PC, I had a similar issue. I found out after lot of fiddling in BIOS that setting SATA port #5 to IDE mode fixed the issue. So just give it a try with each and every parameter in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions, in the hope that they will help :

- Update the BIOS as detailed in this
  [Fit-PC3 Support page](http://fit-pc.com/wiki/index.php/Fit-PC3_BIOS_Update),
  if a newer version to yours does exist.
- Enter BIOS setup and set
  Legacy support for UMS (USB Mass Storage) devices to Disabled, if you have such an option.
  This will only prevent your PC from booting from USB devices, which is not a problem.
  This only affects the BIOS, while Windows will still detect all disks.
- Among the many BIOS versions in existence, the above setting might have other names
  such as
  "Legacy USB storage detect", or "Legacy USB Support" or "USB Device Legacy Support".
  Or they might be separate options. Sometimes these settings may be on an
  "Integrated Peripherals" page in the BIOS.
- Reformat the disk using the Fit-PC3 computer.
- Try a newer enclosure (if it is not new).
  I just lately encountered here a post where an enclosure that internally used
  32-bit addressing had a problem with a disk larger than 2 TB.
- Replace the disk, if still under warranty (but I don't really expect this to help).
- Admit defeat and never boot with this disk turned on.

Comment: I tried setting Legacy Boot to Disabled, and it would not boot from the internal SSD.  It showed me a menu with only the internal SSD listed, but when I selected that it just went black and showed me the menu again.  I got the same behaviour when I enabled UEFI boot (and left legacy disabled).

Comment: Regarding a new enclosure: the drive works on my friend's computer, and is fine on this one after boot time, so I think it must be mostly OK?

Comment: I am nervous to update the BIOS (especially as the page you linked is for Windows only and I only have Linux), and I would prefer not to reformat the disk, so I think I am going to have to take your last option.  Thank you for the time you have put into this.

Comment: The BIOS is common to both Windows or Linux and can usually be launched from a boot USB. But I understand, since a bad BIOS update can brick the computer. I had once the same problem on Windows, tried everything except the BIOS update, and finally I also took the last option ...

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with pc freezing at bios screen everytime ext hdd was connected.
This is what worked for me ;
- just purchased a Dell Optiplex 9020 SFF [used]
- ext hdd [which I was using previously] was now a problem, computer would not boot when it was connected.It would freeze at the Dell BIOS screen.

SOLUTION;
- using Aomei Partiton Assistant Pro, I noticed that c drive [os] was MBR, 2nd drive was     MBR, 3rd drive [ext hdd] was GPT. Using Aomei program, I converted the problem ext hdd which was MBR to GPT with no loss of data.
- went into Dell BIOS and disabled Legacy ROM & USB Boot Support.
 - BINGO! pc will now boot as per normal with ext hdd connected permanently to it.
Hope this helps you!

Comment: This answer, although not written clearly, is actually one valid way to fix the problem. See https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html for a bunch of options on how to fix a modern USB installer that is freezing an older BIOS

Answer (score 0):

My experience with this and my observations. I had a conflict with USB 2.0 and 3.0 that would stop it from booting up. BIOS firmware update can solve 2.0 and 3.0 USB conflicts. I would advise to be certain that 2.0 and 3.0 are correct.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
Disable fast startup in windows 10. 
Windows key + R
powercfg.cpl 
Choose what the power buttons do
Disable Fast Startup

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a Hitachi Touro 2TB external USB hard drive. After trying lots of possible fixes, the only thing that worked was to enable `USB Optimization` in my Intel DQ77MK motherboard BIOS settings. `USB Optimization` is one of three `Fast Boot` settings. Note that `Fast Boot` is not the same as Windows 10's `Fast Startup` option, though both were designed to address the common problem of slow boot times. Here's a description of `USB Optimization`:

> If Enabled, USB devices (keyboards and drives) will not be available
> until after OS boot, but BIOS will boot faster.

The small downside to this fix is that to access the BIOS I now have to hold down the power button until the system beeps, rather than pressing F2 on my USB keyboard.

I'm not sure how common the `USB Optimization` setting is across motherboards, but it's worth a look. [This page](https://vdocuments.site/fast-boot-intel.html) has guidance as to how to find this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post whilst trying to figure out why an older PC would freeze when a bootable USB disk was inserted.

I tried several USB sticks - some USB sticks were fine only to cause a hang when an installer was written to the USB. I had this problem with both an TrueNAS installer and a Tails installer, so it's a general problem rather than the specific installer.

The clue to the solution turned out to be Zed's downvoted answer: this older PC did not like particulars of the GPT partition table.

I was able to fix the installer using the advice from this page: https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html

In specific, using `gdisk` experts menu with the `h` option to recompute the MBR CHS seemed to fix it for me.